# Spring Boot + Angular 4 with i18n

Tags: angular, spring-boot, internationalization

I am currently developing an Angular 4 application with Spring Boot as backend. I use Maven to build the projects configured as explained in https://blog.jdriven.com/2016/12/angular2-spring-boot-getting-started/

I would now like to translate the application in other languages. I looked at http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization for the Spring Boot side, but now I'm wondering if it is possible to use my messages*.properties in Angular. Any experience with that?

Thanks,

Guillaume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is make translation service in Angular. Java API will send messages or even keys and Angular will translate this on client side. You can prepare translation json files and use this library:
https://github.com/ngx-translate/core

Comment: ngx-translate is currently the only way to do this if you need composite translation keys based on data values (like product.type).

There are going to be changes for Angular i18n in upcoming v6 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16477#issuecomment-352125838 which was due to January beta but didn't make it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check my [Spring Boot 2 + Angular 6 starter](https://github.com/milanhlinak/spring-boot-angular-starter). I am using [ngx-translate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-translate/core).

Answer (score 0):

I found good [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-localization-in-angular-using-i18n-tools-a88898b1a0d0/) regarding the angular localization it uses i18n and Angular 7

but here is uses .xlf files to keep the translated messages, which i18n library will use when running the program